# display .msg file in browser using php

Tags: php

I have attached outlook msg file in php application. I am storing that file in sql server database.

Now i want to open and display it from browser.

I tried this code :

```
  if($ext=="msg")
  {
    header('ContentType : application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='. basename($filename));
    echo base64_decode($file);
  }
```

$filename and $file are coming from database.

Its opening msg file in outlook from IE and chrome but its not openning from firefox.

Is there any way to make it working in all the browser ?

Or Am i wrong somewhere or is there any setting in browser ?

Comment: It could be the default firefox behavior. Check Tools -. Options -> Applications tab.

Comment: Thanks Ayesh but I couldn't find anything for outlook msg file in application tab.

Comment: @Mausami How did you create the msg in php, I have been searching all day for such code with no luck?

Answer (score 1):

I had an almost similar situation and was able to solve it.
Include the headers below and it should work just fine.

Regards

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-outlook;charset=UTF-8"); 
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");;
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=test.msg");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#composer require hfig/mapi
# needed if you want to convert to MIME format
#composer require swiftmailer/swiftmailer

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Hfig\MAPI;
use Hfig\MAPI\OLE\Pear;

$decodelocation = '/var/html/tmp/';
$baseurl = 'http://example.com/tmp/';
$uniquefolder = uniqid();
// message parsing and file IO are kept separate
$messageFactory = new MAPI\MapiMessageFactory();
$documentFactory = new Pear\DocumentFactory();

$ole = $documentFactory->createFromFile('source-file.msg');
$message = $messageFactory->parseMessage($ole);

$html = preg_replace_callback($this->regex, "utf8replacer", $message->getBodyHTML());

if (count($message->getAttachments()) > 0) {
foreach ($message->getAttachments() as $attach) {
    $filename = $attach->getFilename();
    $temploc = $decodelocation . '/' . $uniquefolder . '/' . $filename;
    $fileurl = $baseurl . '/' . $uniquefolder . '/' . $filename;
    $replace_string = get_string_between($html, 'cid:' . $filename, '"');
    if ($replace_string) {
        file_put_contents($temploc, $attach->getData());
        $html = str_replace('cid:' . $filename . $replace_string, base_url($temploc), $html);
    } else {
        $geturl = array(
            'filename' => $filename,
            'path' => cencode($temploc),
        );
        $attachments[] = '<a target="_blank" href="' . $fileurl . '">' . $filename . '</a>';
        }
    }
}
foreach ($message->getRecipients() as $recipient) {
    $email = $recipient->getEmail();
    $name = $recipient->getName();
    if ($recipient->getType() == 'From') {
        $From[] = ($name) ? '<a href="mailto:' . $email . '">' . $name . '</a>' : '<a href="mailto:' . $email . '">' . $email . '</a>';
    } elseif ($recipient->getType() == 'To') {
        $To[] = ($name) ? '<a href="mailto:' . $email . '">' . $name . '</a>' : '<a href="mailto:' . $email . '">' . $email . '</a>';
    } elseif ($recipient->getType() == 'Cc') {
        $Cc[] = ($name) ? '<a href="mailto:' . $email . '">' . $name . '</a>' : '<a href="mailto:' . $email . '">' . $email . '</a>';
    } elseif ($recipient->getType() == 'Bcc') {
        $Bcc[] = ($name) ? '<a href="mailto:' . $email . '">' . $name . '</a>' : '<a href="mailto:' . $email . '">' . $email . '</a>';
    }
}
$data = array(
'From' => '<a href="mailto:' . $message->properties['sender_email_address'] . '">' . $message->properties['sender_name'] . '</a>',
'To' => ($To) ? implode('; ', $To) : '',
'Cc' => ($Cc) ? implode('; ', $Cc) : '',
'Bcc' => ($Bcc) ? implode('; ', $Bcc) : '',
'Subject' => $message->properties['subject'],
'hasAttachment' => $message->properties['hasattach'],
'attachments' => ($attachments) ? implode('; ', $attachments) : false,
'html' => $html,
);
#customize your html page using data array. It is take long time for greater than 5 MB.
```

Comment: Yes, I used this code for reading .msg file and display into the HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($ext=="msg")
  {
    header("Content-Type: text/Calendar");
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename='. basename($filename));
    echo base64_decode($file);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks denish. but its not working bcoz it opening file in .ics format rather than .msg so its giving error that filename.ics is not a valid calendar file. Is there any other content type for msg files ?