# open link to a .msg file in outlook

Tags: javascript, php, html, outlook

I am enhancing our client database (php 5.6, js) with some filemanagement components.

If one uploads a file it gets displayed in a list with its name and a link with the pathfile to preview it in the browser (PDFs and IMGs get opened nicely) however if someone decides he needs to upload a .msg file the browserpreview of that file is a mess and not readable at all.

Is there a way to automatically open .msg links with outlook of display it properly in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the similar thread - [display .msg file in browser using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16331169/display-msg-file-in-browser-using-php).

To open an .msg file in Outlook the file should be downloaded and saved on the hard disk, then you need to start a new process specifying the path to the .msg file. I don't think it is possible in PHP. Or you may consider automating Outlook from Internet Explorer (only).

Also you may find third-party components helpful such as [MSG .NET](http://www.independentsoft.de/) or [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/.net/email-component.aspx).

Comment: I am currently using the method to download it automatically - I thought there might be a way to display it nicely in the browser :)