# PHP open .msg file

Tags: php, download, msg

Some users are uploading .msg files to a folder.  I need to be able to open it up in a separate window or just open the original file.

I can open everything that I allow, just not .msg files.

Here is the code I'm using to display and download:

```
<?php
  function listFolderFiles($dir){
    $ffs = scandir($dir);

    foreach($ffs as $ff){
      if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
        if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)){
          // just displaying headers here
        }
        else{
          $filesize = filesize($dir . '/' . $ff);
          echo "<a download href='$dir/$ff'>$ff</a>";
        }
      }
    }
    echo "<br />";
 }
 listFolderFiles('files');
 ?>
```

Not sure if I should post the code I use to upload, but I did include the .msg extension, and the user is indeed able to upload .msg files.

I found this post:  [display .msg file in browser using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16331169/display-msg-file-in-browser-using-php)

And the answer there advised to use various HEADERS.  But I'm not sure why I should place the code for the headers.

Comment: If you're not using PHP then you shouldn't. If you're relying on your webserver to serve up the files for download then you need to configure your web server to do so for the given mime type or file extension. You've provided inclusive information to indicate which direction you intend to go in so I can't provide an answer.

Comment: you want the browser to RENDER those msg files? I'm guessing you mean saved emails?

Comment: Why the downvote?  Was I not clear on my question?  Did I not provide enough proof that I did my research???

Comment: @MarcB - always a pleasure to see comments from you, my friend.  The answer is yes.  They are saved emails and apparently users are uploading them for other users to download.

Comment: browsers aren't mail clients (at least, not anymore since Netscape got broken up). The browser will just treat the .msg as a text file (best case), or as a binary blob and offer to save it. If you want to render the email, you'll have to do the parsing on the server and send out an html representation of it.

Comment: @MarcB - and I'm not sure how the msg files should be rendered.  I guess the browser can render them.